# How to navigate back from UISplitViewController IOS 5?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have 6 views in which I am placing the UISplitViewController at 4th position (i.e.the 4th view). Now when I navigate from 3rd view to 4th view (i.e. ViewController to SplitView) I want to come back to 4th view to 3rd view (i.e. SplitView to ViewController).

I am using the below code to show the UISplitViewController when I am navigating from 3rd view to 4th view.

```
MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];
            UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];

            DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
            UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];

            masterViewController.detailViewController = detailViewController;
            self.splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
            self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
            self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController, nil];
            AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
            appDelegate.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
```

Now I have created a toolbar in my navigation bar programmatically and placed a back button. Below is the code what I have tried to pop the view back to viewcontroller. (i.e. from SplitView to ViewController).

```
-(IBAction)backbtn:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
//    RepresentativeAccount<UISplitViewControllerDelegate> *represent = [[RepresentativeAccount alloc]initWithNibName:@"RepresentativeAccount" bundle:nil];
//    //[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] animated:YES];
//    [[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]popToViewController:represent animated:YES];
}
```

Please help thanks.

Comment: ur english wording is confusing.? Can u put some snapshot(PrintScreen by prssing cmd+shift+4) of ur app. It would be easy for all to know ur problem

Comment: @hpiOSCoder Please check my edited explanation. Please help if u understand my issue.thanks

Comment: hmmm..now ur edited question is explaining the problem.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference: [View Controller Catalog for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313)

> A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you
>   create.

In other words, you must always install the view from a `UISplitViewController` object as the *root view* of your application’s window.

> The panes of your split view interface may then contain navigation
>   controllers, tab bar controllers, or any other type of view controller
>   you need to implement your interface.

Split view controllers cannot be presented modally.

So, what you are attempting is incorrect, and in fact your app may get rejected by Apple.

Comment: In a default project the `split view controller` is already added and we need to have a possibility to pop it